# {exp:stash:get_list} sorting by a numeric column

Tags: stash

Having tested {exp:stash:get_list}, I found out that any numeric column used as a reference for sorting is evaluated as a string, not as a number.

So I get something like this in order,

```
1
10
11
12
...
2
20
21
22
...
3
```

How do I make it so that it evaluates that column as a number?

**Example Code**

```
{exp:stash:set_list name="message_list_items" parse_tags="yes"}
    {exp:example:message
        conversation_id="{segment_2}"
        limit="{limit}"
        paginate="bottom"
        sort="desc"
    }
        {if '{count}' == 1}
            {stash:opening_tag}
            {!- Some Stuff here --}
            <ol>
            {/stash:opening_tag}
        {/if}
        {stash:message_order}{count}{/stash:message_order}
        {stash:message}
                <li>
                    {!- Some Stuff here --}
                </li>
        {/stash:message}
    {/exp:example:message}
{/exp:stash:set_list}

{exp:stash:get_list
    name="message_list_items"
    {if '{embed:arbitrary_condition}' != 'y'}
        orderby="message_order"
        sort="asc"
    {/if}
}
    {if '{count}' == 1}
        {opening_tag}
    {/if}
    {message_order}
    {message}
{/exp:stash:get_list}
{/ol}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `sort_type="integer"` parameter when you use `get_list`. That might help you out.

Here's the wiki for the [get_list](https://github.com/croxton/Stash/wiki/%7Bexp%3Astash%3Aget_list%7D).

Answer (score 0):

I think, you are setting channel entries as list via Stash. Right? If so see that channel field's settings for `Field Content` under `Field Options` and select it as `Number`. You set_list/get_list would work properly by sorting with number.

Comment: I am actually just using {count} or {message_id}(list of messages) so I actually don't have control over the field content.

Comment: Can you please share how are you setting list via stash? If would help other guys to answer.

Comment: I have added some example code.